# ошибка PHP Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, ajax, index

Доброго времени суток!Возник такой вопрос, не записываются в базу два значения, `$ratCom`   и `$ratingDisk` возникает ошибка вида `[09-Mar-2018 08:26:43 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ratCom in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public_html/Feedback/load.php on line 21` 
подскажите в чем проблема и как ее исправить?

> JS-код

```
        $('#rev').on('click', function  () {
   firstName = $('#firstName').val();
   lastName = $('#lastName').val();
   textarea1 = $('#exampleFormControlTextarea1').val();
   ratEvent = $("select[name=ratingEv]").val();
   ratCom = $("select[name=ratingCom]").val();
   ratingProg = $("select[name=ratingProg]").val();
   ratingPart = $("select[name=ratingPart]").val();
   ratingDisk = $("select[name=ratingDisk]").val();
   checkPub = $('#same-address').is(':checked');
   checkInf = $('#save-info').is(':checked');
   checkInf = $('#save-info').is(':checked');
   var status = $("select[name=stat]").val();
   var dataString = 'firstName='+ firstName + '&lastName=' + lastName + '&textarea1=' + textarea1 +  '&ratEvent=' + ratEvent + '&ratCom =' + ratCom  + '&ratingProg=' + ratingProg +'&ratingPart=' + ratingPart + '&ratingDisk' + ratingDisk + '&checkPub=' + checkPub + '&checkInf=' + checkInf+ '&resp=' + resp+ '&status=' + status;
   $.ajax({
      url: "load.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: dataString,
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });

 });
```

> PHP-код

```
 <?php



if(!$_POST) exit;

    if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="root"; //установленный вами пароль
    $db_name="u997029462_bo";

    $link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysqli_select_db($link,$db_name);

    $firstName      = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName       = $_POST['lastName'];
    $textarea1      = $_POST['textarea1'];
    $ratEvent       = $_POST['ratEvent'];
    $ratCom         = $_POST['ratCom'];
    $ratingProg     = $_POST['ratingProg'];
    $ratingPart     = $_POST['ratingPart'];
    $ratingDisk     = $_POST['ratingDisk'];
    $checkPub       = $_POST['checkPub'];
    $checkInf       = $_POST['checkInf'];
    $resp           = $_POST['resp'];
    $status         = $_POST['status'];



    if (isset($_POST["firstName"])||isset($_POST["lastName"])||isset($_POST["textarea1"])||isset($_POST["ratEvent"])||isset($_POST["ratCom"])||isset($_POST["ratingProg"])||isset($_POST["ratingPart"])||isset($_POST["ratingDisk"])||isset($_POST["checkPub"])||isset($_POST["checkInf"])||isset($_POST["resp"])||isset($_POST["status"])) 
    {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
        $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `comment` (`Name`,`surname`, `status`,`comment`, `EventRating`,`OrganizationalCommitteeRating`,`ProgramRatingOfTheEvent`, `RatingOfPartners`,`DiscothequeRating`,`Publication`,`Notice`,`Photo`,`Date`) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$status','$textarea1','$ratEvent','$ratCom','$ratingProg','$ratingPart','$ratingDisk','$checkPub','$checkInf','$resp','$date')";
    $query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
    if ($query) {
        echo $_POST['ratingDisk'];
        echo $query;
    } else {
        echo $query;
        echo $_POST['ratCom'];
    }
}
```

Comment: В одном случае перед = пробел, во-втором случае нет знака =. Вторая подсказка - смотрите в код js.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо большое, это все моя не внимательность